# Giving a string variable as a filename in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, filenames

I am using the below mentioned code to get the file names of images according to their id's from images_1 text file as strings and use them to read the images from their directory

```
image_count=1;
for image_count=1:6
    file=fopen('D:\Academics\New folder\CUB_200_2011\images_1.txt','r');
    C = textscan(file, '%s');
    original_image=imread('D:\Academics\New folder\CUB_200_2011\images\%s','C{1}{2*(image_count)}');
    imshow(original_image)
end
```

I am able to get the file name but not able to use it.
This code shows the following error-

> 'File "D:\Academics\New folder\CUB_200_2011\images\%s" does not exist.

I am a bit new to matlab, can anyone please help me.

Comment: How are your filenames stored in images_1.txt? Do they contain the full path to the image or just the file names (eg: "image_2.png", etc)?

Comment: They are actually full paths like this giving the folder name and file name-01.Black_footed_Albatross/Black_Footed_Albatross_0046_18.jpg

Comment: The `%s` construct in `imread` will not be replaced by the second argument. Use `strcat` to concatenate the path and the filename. So you can call like this: `imread(strcat('D:\Academics\New folder\CUB_200_2011\images\',C{1}{2*(image_count)}))`

Comment: @Matt That's what I thought so I said to use `sprintf`. But I guess there are more issues.

Comment: but strcat also doesn't work, it shows-File "D:\Academics\New
folder\CUB_200_2011\images\%s001.Black_footed_Albatross/Black_Footed_Albatross_0046_18.jpg"
does not exist.   Its not replacing %s

Comment: @AkhilKumar it is not supposed to replace `%s`. remove it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate parts of your file path, you have to use `fullfile`

```
 imread(fullfile('D:\Academics\New folder\CUB_200_2011\images\',C{1}{2*(image_count)}))
```

Strcat is an alternative, but fullfile takes care of having one file separator wherever needed.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to change your back slashes `\` to forward slashes `/`, otherwise some `\` followed by a letter may be commands in the `sprintf`function, like for example `\N` or `\a`. See [sprintf documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) in the `formatSpec`area for more information.

```
original_image=imread(sprintf('D:/Academics/New folder/CUB_200_2011/images/%s', C{1}{2*(image_count)}));
```

Comment: This is showing the following error-                                                 Warning: Escape sequence 'A' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape sequences. 
Error using imread (line 367)
Can't open file "D:" for reading;                                                                       
you may not have read permission.                                                                     should I change the path of the images

Comment: what is `C{1}{2*(image_count)}` ?

Comment: That has the image directory and the image name like this-     01.Black_footed_Albatross/Black_Footed_Albatross_0046_18.jpg

Comment: Yes, but if you pass it to the `whos` function, what do you get?

Comment: I've added some explanation in the answer.

Comment: Using forward slashes just to get around string escaping is a bad idea, they don't work properly in any case.

Comment: @Daniel They work properly even in windows. Why do you say that? I've never had any problem.

Comment: Batch scripts are likely to fail, only to give one example